# Где найти драйвер ODBC x32 bit для psqlodbc_09_05

Tags: postgresql, excel, odbc

Где найти драйвер ODBC x32 bit для `psqlodbc_09_05`?

Столкнулся с проблемой, не могу найти 32 битный драйвер для подсоединения exel к базе postgres.

Answer (score -1):

Необходимо ввести в cmd  `%systemdrive%\Windows\SysWoW64`
и там настроить подключение, используя 64 битный драйвер, проблем не возникнет

Comment: Из ответа не вполне понятно, где можно *найти* драйвер. Если искать ничего не нужно, а достаточно просто настроить — напишите об этом явно, пожалуйста.

Comment: Перечитал ещё раз. Смысл в том, что можно вместо 32-битного использовать 64-битный и он будет работать на 32-битной системе, так?